# Should we have a Deferral tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging, tagging

I am currently in a situation were I would like to defer a PhD admissions offer, and I am searching for other users' deferral experience and questions. However there is no deferral Tag. Should we create one?

Or is there an existing tag that serves this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be a situation where a new tag is appropriate. Deferral of offers is not just specific to admissions, but can also apply to postdoc and faculty job offers.